# Ejecutar script de Google Sheets sin ser el propietario

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una hoja en la que se deben ingresar fechas en la columna A. Éstas deben ser ingresadas ejecutando un script que está en la barra de menú.

La columna A está protegida para todos los usuarios excepto para mi *que soy el que la creó*. No quiero que las fechas puedan ser ingresadas a mano sino solamente ejecutando el script.

La fecha la copia de otra hoja y la pega como "value" para que no se modifique cuando la hoja se actualiza.

Cuando yo lo ejecuto no da ningún problema, pero cuando lo ejecuta otra persona a la que he compartido la hoja, da la advertencia de que la columna está protegida.

¿Cómo retiro temporalmente la protección con el script, o cómo un usuario ejecuta el script bajo mi nombre?

Este es el código:

```
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('OTROS DATOS')
    .addItem('Ingresa Fecha Actual', 'getRangeValue')
   .addToUi();
 }

//******************** INGRESA FECHA ACTUAL EN CELDA ACTUAL *************************
function getRangeValue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('Validadores!A2');
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var R = cell.getRow();
  var C = cell.getColumn();
  range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(R,C), {contentsOnly:true}); 
 }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Ademas lee: **[¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

La forma de retirar temporalmente la protección es que tu mismo lo hagas manualmente, mediante un disparador instalable o una aplicación web. Una alternativa que la actualización de datos sobre el rango protegido, se realice mediante una aplicación web configurada para ser ejecutada con permisos del propietario.

## Explicación

En este caso se trata de un proyecto de secuencias de comando (scripts) "amarrado a un contenedor", en inglés a "container bounded script". En este tipo de proyectos, los scripts se ejecutan con los permisos que tiene el usuario sobre el documento, así que el usuario no tiene permiso para editar un rango, tampoco podrá hacerlo mediante un script que forme parte del *container bounded script*.

Cabe mencionar que para ejecutar un script con los permisos del propietario, lo que se suele hacer es crear una aplicación web (web app) ya que en estas es posible determinar si serán ejecutadas con los permisos del usuario o con los del dueño del script. Obviamente, en este caso habría que configurar la web app para que sea ejecutada como los permisos del propietario.

Lamentablemente el integrar la web app con la interfaz de usuario de la hoja de cálculo no es del todo apropiada, ya que si bien es posible incluir el enlace a la aplicación web, al hacer clic en este se abre una nueva ventana o bien se modifica el contenido del diálogo modal, lo que resulta poco intuitivo.

Comment: Bueno, muchas gracias por la información. Concluyo entonces que un script no puede quitar el bloqueo cuando es ejecutado por otro sujeto que no sea el propietario. Es penoso que así resulte, porque sería una interesante opción para que una hoja solamente pueda ser manipulada a través de un script. Mil gracias el tiempo dedicado